# use spring data to connect to datastore google cloud

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore

How can i use Spring Data in order to connect to DataStore google, actually i use  com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1

But my lead Manager want use spring-Data with dataStore how can i do that?

for example to insert an Entity i actually use:

```
    public void insert(Entity entity) {
    Datastore datastore = this.datastoreFactory.getInstance();
    CommitRequest request = 
    CommitRequest.newBuilder().setMode(CommitRequest.Mode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL)

   .setMutation(Mutation.newBuilder().addInsertAutoId(entity)).build();
    try {
        CommitResponse response = datastore.commit(request);
    } catch (DatastoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




   @Override
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public Datastore getInstance() {

    if(datastore != null)
        return datastore;
    try {
        // Setup the connection to Google Cloud Datastore and infer
        // credentials
        // from the environment.
        //the environment variables DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT and    
        DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE must be set
        datastore = DatastoreFactory.get().create(

       DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv().dataset(Constant.ProjectId)
                        .build());



      } catch (GeneralSecurityException exception) {
        System.err.println("Security error connecting to the datastore: "
                + exception.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("I/O error connecting to the datastore: "
                + exception.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return datastore;

  }
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you can use App Engine's DataNucleus JPA with Spring Data JPA, as per this tutorial: tommysiu.blogspot.com/2014/01/spring-data-on-gae-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

To use Spring Data with a specific storage you need to implement a bunch of interfaces from Spring Data Commons. Take a look at the GCP Spanner Spring Data implementation as an example (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner)